# PHP can't run python script that downloads a video

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

I want a PHP script to run this code:
thanks for reading (or helping)

PHP can run a simple `Print('hello world')` .py file, but won't run this code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pytube import YouTube
import sys
print('....Video Downloading....')
YouTube(sys.argv[1]).streams.first().download('videos')
print('DONE!')
```

The PHP *command* is

```
$URL = $_GET['url'];
$fi = new FilesystemIterator('videos', FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
printf("<br>There were %d Files", iterator_count($fi));
echo "<br><br>DEBUG:<br>";
$command = "/usr/bin/python3.6 main.py $URL";
//$command = 'whoami';
exec($command, $out, $status);
print_r($out);
echo "....".$status;
echo "<br>end DEBUG<br><br>";
```

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but use double quotes marks if you want to parse variables.

Comment: `$command = 'python3 main.py $URL';` will NOT be interpreted correctly so, as @Amarnasan says, use double quotes.

Comment: @RamRaider. Sorry, I coppied the the code wrong, it does use the "(double ') to ensure $VAR works.

Comment: @Amarnasan Sorry, I coppied the the code wrong, it does use the "(double ') to ensure $VAR works. –

Comment: But ... that's all the PHP script has? assigning a string to a variable? You don't run that string using a call to "system","exec" or "passthru"?

Comment: @Amarnasan I just re-updated the code with exactly whats in the PHP fie

Comment: Define "won't run this code"